# How do I get away from Select and Copy and write better code?

Tags: excel, vba

Can you explain how I can get away from using select and copy in this code? I want to make it run as efficiently as possible and without screen updating. I know I can set the screenupdating = false, but i prefer to just have the code written better!

```
Dim i As Integer

        For i = 4 To 501

            Sheets("Repository").Range("B" & i).Copy
            Sheets("Input").Activate
            Sheets("Input").Range("M13").Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

            Sheets("Input").Range("M21").Copy
            Sheets("Repository").Activate
            Sheets("Repository").Range("E" & i).Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues


            Sheets("Input").Range("U12").Copy
            Sheets("Repository").Activate
            Sheets("Repository").Range("C" & i).Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

            Sheets("Input").Range("V12").Copy
            Sheets("Repository").Activate
            Sheets("Repository").Range("D" & i).Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

        Next i
```

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're only moving values from one cell to another, there's no need to copy/paste.  If you have to copy a lot of formatting over then there may be a need for it.  This should accomplish the same thing, in my view it's the simplest way to go about it--

```
Dim wsRepository as Worksheet
Set wsRepository = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Repository")

Dim wsInput as Worksheet
Set wsInput = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input")

Dim i As Integer
For i = 4 To 501

    wsInput.Range("M13") = wsRepository.Range("B" & i)

    wsRepository.Range("E" & i) = wsInput.Range("M21")

    wsRepository.Range("C" & i) = wsInput.Range("U12")

    wsRepository.Range("D" & i) = wsInput.Range("V12")

Next i
```

Comment: What is the benefit in defining wsRepository (Set) are you speeding up the calculation time? Or is it just good practice? Why shouldn't I just define it each time in my code?

Comment: @user1813558 It's good practice for a few reasons - it's shorter and cleaner looking, if you need to change the worksheet name you only have to do it in one place, and most importantly it tells VBA precisely which worksheet you want to work on. So in your case, if you had two workbooks open, and both had sheets name Respository and Input, and you clicked or activated the wrong one while the code was running, it would start running the code on the wrong workbook.  Try and specify the excel instance, workbook, and worksheet whenever possible -

Comment: e700k's tip about using the `.end(xldown).row` trick instead of hardcoding the number of lines (501) is for sure something you will want to know too - appreciate the acceptance, it's great to see someone trying to progress in vba, keep at it!

Answer (score 0):

You can eliminate a lot of the activating and selecting.  Here's how I would write it:

```
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        For i = 4 To 501

            Sheets("Repository").Range("B" & i).Copy
            Sheets("Input").Range("M13").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

            Sheets("Input").Range("M21").Copy
            Sheets("Repository").Range("E" & i).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues


            Sheets("Input").Range("U12").Copy
            Sheets("Repository").Range("C" & i).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

            Sheets("Input").Range("V12").Copy
            Sheets("Repository").Range("D" & i).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

        Next i
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

I would still recommend setting screenupdate to false.  It will run a lot faster if it doesn't need to show the user each action it's taking.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you don't need to select/activate/copy... you can simply assign values from one cell to another (with/without using variables). I would do  this:

```
Sub test()

Dim i As Long 'Integer has a strict limit
Dim j As Integer
Dim RepositoryWs As Worksheet
Dim InputWs As Worksheet
Dim destinationCell(1 To 4) As Range
Dim sourceCell(1 To 4) As Range

Set RepositoryWs = Worksheets("Repository")
Set InputWs = Worksheets("Input")

'Static ranges
With InputWs

    Set destinationCell(1) = .Range("M13")
    Set sourceCell(2) = .Range("M21")
    Set sourceCell(3) = .Range("U12")
    Set sourceCell(4) = .Range("V12")

End With

For i = 4 To RepositoryWs.Range("B4").End(xlDown).Row 'Not hardcoded -> it works if you'll have more data on Repository sheet

    'Dynamic ranges
    With RepositoryWs

        Set sourceCell(1) = .Range("B" & i)
        Set destinationCell(2) = .Range("E" & i)
        Set destinationCell(3) = .Range("C" & i)
        Set destinationCell(4) = .Range("D" & i)

    End With

    For j = 1 To 4

        destinationCell(j).Value = sourceCell(j).Value

    Next j

Next i

End Sub
```